# Authentication system in Rails 3 . Devise / omniauth or self coded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I am a newbie in ROR developement. I am trying to create my own application with the help of Ruby on Rails tutorial 2nd edition. I made many reseaches. I need your comments about devise or any other authentications system or as the book offers us to write our own authentication systems.

What are your ideas? Is it wasting time to write your own authentication system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm quite new to RoR myself but i used Devise so far (and according to the book i'm currently reading it is worth it).

You could use the Railscasts about Devise if you want an introduction to it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

And as it is quite easy to learn and well featured i'd say it is pretty overkill to write your own.

Answer (score 2):

I am a huge advocate of Devise, and also of not recreating the wheel. My rebuttal question would be why go through the trouble of creating your own authentication solution, when in just a few short bash commands, Devise will be installed and running. The configuration options alone are enough to choose Devise, not to mention that almost every part of the engine has the ability to be overridden with your own code.

There are hundreds of blog posts out there that can easily get you started with running Devise. As always with any gem, I would recommend starting out with browsing the [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), and then turning to the [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) for the answers that you seek. As @krizz mentioned, Ryan Bates' Railscasts are always a great place to turn when you need to see it setup.

And of course, you can always turn back here to the stack when you get stuck.